# Bind a function to Bootstrap Modal Cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I know we can bind a function to bootstrap modal for close event like this:

```
$("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){ 
    //run the script
});
```

I need to know, when the dialog is canceled, but this also is triggered when the dialog is clicked "OK". How can I filter this? I need to know, when the dialog is hidden but not the primary button clicked.

Thankyou.

Comment: Do you need to know when the dialog box is hidden because you click cancel?

Comment: I suggest you add an ID to the `Cancel` button and just use `$('#modal-close').click(function() { ... });`

Comment: Not just the click on cancel, also the click outside the modal and on the cross in the upper corner or press ESC.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add an ID to the modal close button and use jQuery's `click()` function to detect when it's clicked.

Here's an example

```js
$('#modal-close-btn').click(function() {
  console.log("MODAL CLOSED");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- ... -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="modal-close-btn" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about this, but what's about the cross in the upper corner, or when the user clicks outside the modal or by ESC. My approach is to avoid these possibilities and then listen to that event like you suggested. Hoped there where another way.

Comment: @Juliane only buttons with the attribute of `data-dismiss="modal"` will dismiss the modal, all other buttons will not. Maybe you can use this knowledge to your advantage. You must have some function that is run when the user hit's the `Save` button rather than `Close` right

Comment: I had this idea too, but what about teh click outside the modal? I solved it that I forbid to close the dialog by clicking outside or ESC and removed the cross. Just listen to the cancel button. Seems there is no other short way. ThankYou